Can I re apply as a PR in Singapore
I was planning to re apply as a PR in Singapore,is there any chance they will accept me ,I lost my PR since I didn't back to Singapore last pandemic ,and I re announce it last year ,but I don't get my CPF yet ,I was planning to re apply if it possible they can accept my application or not?

What is CPF? Do you meet the eligibility criteria?
